# implode и многомерные массивы

Tags: php

Мне нужно в логах красиво, С ОТСТУПАМИ выводить многомерные массивы. Пока у меня есть функция для вывода без отступов:

```
function multi_implode($sep, $array) {
    foreach($array as $val)
        $_array[] = is_array($val)? $this->multi_implode($sep, $val) : $val;
    return implode($sep, $_array);
}
```

Как добавить отступы чтобы было красиво ? )

Comment: Сделайте функции еще 1 параметр, я бы его level назвал и вызывайте ее с 1 в этом параметре а она себя рекурсивно будет вызывать с level+1 и по нему уже ориентируйтесь на какой глубине рекурсии вы находитесь и сколько отступов сделать

Comment: Level можно сделать по умолчанию равным 1.

Comment: `print_r()` - не? Оно и пофункциональней будет :)

Comment: print_r() и var_export для меня слишком просто ))) только хардкор! )
С уровнями идея понравилась, спасибо ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = var_export($array, TRUE);
```